# Is it possible to download and save file using adobe air?

Tags: flash, air, download, directory, local

i made a flash air application for android and i need to download file and save to application local directory

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 6):

URLRequest and URLLoader will allow you to fetch some data from the internet, FileStream allows you to save it locally (FileReference if you want them to choose where to save it) as in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete_handler);
                urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
                urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckboxList/CheckboxList.swf"));

            }

            private function complete_handler(event:Event):void
            {
                var data:ByteArray = event.target.data;

                var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
                fr.save(data, 'test.swf');

                var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                trace(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath);
                fileStream.open(new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"\\test.swf"),FileMode.WRITE);
                fileStream.writeBytes(data, 0, data.length);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

**EDIT:**
AS3 Mobile project version:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class DownloadFileMobileAS3 extends Sprite
    {
        public function DownloadFileMobileAS3()
        {
            super();

            // support autoOrients
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            createLoader();
        }
        protected function createLoader():void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete_handler);
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckboxList/CheckboxList.swf"));

        }

        private function complete_handler(event:Event):void
        {
            var data:ByteArray = event.target.data;

            var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
            fr.save(data, 'test.swf');

            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            trace("something");
            trace(File.applicationDirectory);
            trace(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath);
            trace(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath);
            fileStream.open(new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath+"\\test.swf"),FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStream.writeBytes(data, 0, data.length);
        }
    }
}
```

I included both options in the code above you would want to either take out the file reference part or take out the file stream part otherwise it'll be saved twice.

I just added the mobile section, it in fact does have some sort of dialog it prompts you with for saving a file on Android, though it's a dialog I've never seen before, just gives you the option of where to save it and Audio Files, Image Files, and Video Files as options or a default location at /mnt/sdcard/test.swf.  I let it save there and am able to see it using ES Explorer (though I had no good way to verify the data was in tact it appears generally to be correct).  The one using the applicationDirectory was failing on me, tracing it out I was seeing no nativePath so I switched it to applicationStorageDirectory which had a value and it seems to have saved without error, unfortunately it's in my root /data folder and since I don't have my phone rooted I have no way to completely confirm the file is actually there but no errors.  Let me know if you've tried this and what specific issues you're still encountering.

Comment: Thanks for helping he but i am using this code for flash i had done everything to make suit for flash but not worked.If you know how to make suit this code for flash please help..

Comment: Hey Pabo, aside from the application as the container and using the creation complete event I don't think I'm really depending on anything in Flex for this to work, it should all be available in Flash... I'll make a flash mobile project and throw it in there to see if I get any issues, the only thing I could think of that may be a problem is using the file reference since I don't know how that works on mobile platforms, generally it's requesting a OS specific pop-up for selecting a file or a location to save but there is no built-in file system browser I'm aware of on Android or iOS.

Comment: I updated my answer, also to note I checked allow writing to external storage when creating the project so it would add that to the -app.xml file and ultimately the apk installed on the device.

Comment: shaunhusain, really thanks for helping.Your code worked on my android phone. But the problem is i am making a magazine application when person click on update button the image need to be download automatically with out asking the location where the files need to be save.Your code is great i couldn't done this much yet but problem is i don't want that dialog box where the file need to save.If know how do that please help.Thanks a lot for help me

Comment: If you remove the FileReference part the user won't be prompted, the next step then is to determine how to save the file where you want to save it, are you going for saving it directly to a pictures folder or otherwise where, basically you can use the FileStream to save where-ever without prompting the user, however you just need to figure out how to get what that path is using the File classes static properties (most likely).  So what's the specific folder you want to save the data into?

Comment: Thanks Shaun Husain for helping me the code works pretty well.:):):)