# AS3 Air for Android [Error 2070] - Remotely loaded SWF cannot access Stage from App

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am building an Air for Android (AS3) application that will load remote swf files (located on my server)

The idea is to keep the apk as stream lined as possible to allow fast deployment (will be deployed privately and not over Google Play)

- The apk is called the Loader
- The remote swf is called the Player.

Now, Player is throwing up this error when I launch Loader:

> SecurityError: Error #2070: Security sandbox violation: caller http://sub.mydomain.com/remote/player.swf cannot access Stage owned by app:/Loader.swf.

This is odd as Player does not try to call the Loader stage - I told Player to make a new stage called "_stage", code below:

```
var playerContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var _stage:Stage = playerContainer.stage;
```

Using:

```
_stage.stageWidth
```

to access the stage width.

I have no idea why Loader thinks Player is trying to access it's stage properties?

I have tried the following pieces of code that I have seen mentioned in various forum posts, but nothing seems to alleviate the problem with the security domains:

In Loader

```
try {Security.allowDomain("*");}catch (e) { };
```

In Player

```
Security.allowDomain("http://sub.mydomain.com");
```

and also in Player, for my init() function

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, displayLogin);
```

Neither of these help.

I am at a total loss. It's above my head as to how to get Loader to allow Player access to its stage properties.

EDIT - when both swf files are on the server, and I access Loader via a browser, rather then using the android app, it loads fine. Definitely an issue with cross scripting, but it looks to me like I have all the right code to allow that?

Answer (score 0):

Pablo,
first if it adds item to the stage than it access the stage property, maybe you should download the player.swf to SDCard or apps local storage and loaded it from there? You could then set expire date after which you will reload the player.swf?

[Here is the link to other SO Question about storing remote file on SDCARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854165/is-it-possible-to-download-and-save-file-using-adobe-air)

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of how to go about downloading the player to local storage and embedding that instead of the remote file?